# Pandas - How to merge rows with blank columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I am trying to use pandas (is new to me) to combine/merge similar CSV rows into a single row but can't seem to figure it out. Am open to other python solutions if they are better/easier.

There are a lot of posts about combining/merging using pandas but the ones I have seen are summing or combining the values when the rows are combined, not replacing a null with a value when merged. I tried using df.drop_duplicates but the rows aren't really duplicates so it didn't do anything.

CSV format:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
A     B     D     6     null  null
A     B     E     8     null  null
A     B     F     10    null  null
A     B     D     null  20    null
A     B     E     null  22    null
A     B     F     null  24    null
A     B     D     null  null  44
A     B     E     null  null  46
A     B     F     null  null  48
A     B     G     null  null  50
A     C     D     6     null  null
A     C     E     8     null  null
A     C     F     10    null  null
A     C     D     null  20    null
A     C     E     null  22    null
A     C     F     null  24    null
A     C     D     null  null  44
A     C     E     null  null  46
A     C     F     null  null  48
H     I     D     12    null  null
H     I     J     14    null  null
H     I     K     16    null  null
H     I     D     null  26    null
H     I     J     null  28    null
H     I     K     null  30    null
H     I     D     null  null  52
H     I     J     null  null  54
H     I     K     null  null  56
```

Expected/needed output:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
A     B     D     6     20    44
A     B     D     8     22    46
A     B     D     10    24    48
A     B     G     null  null  50
A     C     D     6     20    44
A     C     D     8     22    46
A     C     D     10    24    48
H     I     D     12    26    52
H     I     J     14    28    54
H     I     K     16    30    56
```

Comment: If you are sure that the values are unique for each combination of columns 1,2 and 3; you can try groupby and sum or max. new_df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], as_index = False).max()

Comment: Thanks @Vaishali! That appears to have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `first`

```
df=df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).first().reset_index()
df
  col1 col2 col3  col4  col5  col6
0    A    B    D   6.0  20.0  44.0
1    A    B    E   8.0  22.0  46.0
2    A    B    F  10.0  24.0  48.0
3    A    B    G   NaN   NaN  50.0
4    A    C    D   6.0  20.0  44.0
5    A    C    E   8.0  22.0  46.0
6    A    C    F  10.0  24.0  48.0
7    H    I    D  12.0  26.0  52.0
8    H    I    J  14.0  28.0  54.0
9    H    I    K  16.0  30.0  56.0
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The resulting CSV looks pretty much the same.

Comment: @mikenol you need to assign it back `df=df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).first().reset_index()
`

Comment: Thanks @WeNYoBen. That's what it was. I was using just:
```df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).first().reset_index()```  
```df.to_csv('file.csv')```  
It worked when I did df=df...