# Get all data in the same row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: id, single, age.

```
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
    'single': ['y', '', '', '', 'n', 'n', '', 'y'],
    'age': ['', 22, '', 34, '', 22, '', 43]
}
```

Some rows of the same id have NaN values and others have info.

I want something like:

```
data = {
    'id': [1,2,3, 4],
    'single': ['y' 'n', 'n', 'y'],
    'age': [22,  34, 22,  43]
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `df.replace('', np.nan).groupby('id', as_index=False).first()`

Comment: Also duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300682/pandas-how-to-merge-rows-with-blank-columns

Answer (score 1):

Just use `groupby` and `first`. Replace the '' with `np.nan` before that.

```
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df_new = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
```